# Cannot get ExportTablesToExcelFiles.wwd script to work properly with PASW 18 (SPSS) and Excel 2013

Tags: vba, export-to-excel, spss

The ExportTablesToExcelFiles.wwd script (written in VBA) will not work properly with PASW 18 (SPSS) and Excel 2013. It will not export more than one table from the PASW Statistics Viewer no matter what configuration I use in the export table dialog box. ExportTablesToExcelFiles.wwd is also supposed to export the tables into xlsx format but it has only exported to xls. This script is supposed to work with PASW 16 and later, and Excel 2010 and later. Has anyone ran into similar problems when using the script?

I should mention that I'm trying to export ten tables that are about 1500 rows each.

The script can be found here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/files/app#/person/270002VCWN/file/8e0dfcb6-aa57-4639-a20e-1780010cfe83.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script does export all, all visible, or selected tables according to the radio button you choose.  Whether you get xls or xlsx files depends on which version of Excel you have installed, since it uses Excel VBA automation.  As a practical matter, xls files work fine in later versions of Excel anyway.  However, it has not been tested with Excel 2013, which I don't have available.  I'll see if I can test on a system that has that version of Excel.

If you are only getting one table exported, is there an error message appearing anywhere - in the Viewer or as an alert?

Comment: Apologies for not getting back to you in a timely manner. I upgraded to SPSS 19 and that fixed all of the problems. The script just wouldn't work well with PASW 18. There were never any error messages when I used the script in PASW 18. Thanks for you help.

Comment: How can you run this script in SPSS 24? Do I select the tables I need first and then.... ?

Comment: The script brings up a dialog box that lets you choose between all tables, all visible tables, or all selected tables.